# Attempt to index global 'p' (a nil value) on line 133

Tags: indexing, lua, love2d

I've been trying to make a main menu for a small project my friend and I are working on. I came across this error on line 133 which is used for player gravity (my friend coded that part). Hear is the code, help would be appreciated:

I couldn't get the code block to work so put it on this URL

http://pastebin.com/ue09X0Bi

P.S very sorry i couldn't get the code block to work.

Answer (score 2):

The global variable `p` is used throughout the code but is not assigned anywhere, so its value is logically `nil`.

Note: it is unusual and not recommendable to have a global variable with a such short name.

EDIT: from the new link you provide in the comment, `p` is set inside function `loadgeneral` contained in `player.lua`. This means that `loadgeneral` is not called, although it is present at line 19 in function `love.load` of your script. This is probably normal, since `gamestate` is there set to `"menu"` and you immediately compare that variable to `"playing"`, which will always yield false!